# Summation with constraints

Tags: summation

I am trying to do the summation shown below,
$\sum_{i_1=0}^{imax_1} \sum_{i_2=0}^{imax_2} \dots \sum_{i_k=0}^{imax_k} f(i_1,\dots,i_k)$

$k$ is a variable. Therefore $i$ and $imax$ are defined as arrays of length $k$.

```
Array[i,k]
Array[imax,k]
```

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Comment: Did you try `Sum[f,{i,imin,imax},{j,jmin,jmax}]`? Maybe you can take a look at [this](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/SumsAndProducts.html) and [this](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Sum.html).

Comment: will that work when i is an array?

Comment: Do you have any code which you've already tried to use? As far as I know you could also use `{i,imin,imax,di}`,where `di` is the step size.

Comment: If the terms of your sum are all in an array, you can do this: `Total[Array[f[#1, #2, ...] &, {imax1, imax2, ...}, {0, 0, ...}], -1]`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quite neat solution (*if indices are from 0 to imax*):

```
imax = RandomInteger[{1, 5}, k]
```

> ```
> {1, 2, 1, 1}
> ```

```
Total[f @@@ Tuples[Range[0, #] & /@ imax]]
```

> ```
> f[0, 0, 0, 0] + f[0, 0, 0, 1] + f[0, 0, 1, 0] + f[0, 0, 1, 1] + ...
> ```

**Extension** for case with imin different from 0.

```
Total[f @@@ Tuples[Range[##] & @@@ Transpose[{imin, imax}]]]
```

**Edit:**
I am struggling with question if `Array[i,k]` is argument for *f* or set of indices to Array with values. Above solution is for the former. Latter can be easily achieved by following definition:

```
f[x__] := g @@ (a /@ {x})
```

if it is not clear one should evaluate this and then `Total[...`:

> ```
> g[a[1], a[1], a[0], a[1]] + ....
> ```

Maybe this way for the last case is clearer:

```
Composition[
  Total,
  Apply[f, #, {1}] &, (* {1,2} -> f[1,2] *)
  Map[i, #, {2}] &, (* 1 -> i[1]*)
  Tuples,
  Map[Range[0, #] &, #] & (*creating sets of indices from 0 to imax_i*)
  ][imax]
```

> ```
> f[i[0], i[0], i[0]] + f[i[0], i[0], i[1]] +...
> ```

So for more complicated cases I wolud choose halirutan's solution as shorter.

Comment: `i` and `imax` are defined as arrays... so it might be possible to `i` to be, for instance, greater than `imax`. In this case I believe the code wouldn't work...

Comment: @RodLm It seems I was thinkging about something else. If I understand well Your concern: don't worry, if `Length@i > Max@imax` it is going to works too.

Comment: I'd rather use e.g. `Total[f @@@ Tuples[Range[0, #] & /@ imax]] // Short` for appropriate formatting instead of `...`.

Comment: @Artes Good point. I'll keep that in mind. I have just found `Shallow`, it suits well too.

Comment: i is the argument to the function. So f(i_):= blah where i is an Array.

Comment: How do I convert 

f[0, 0, 0, 0] + f[0, 0, 0, 1] +  ... 
to
f[{0, 0, 0, 0}] + f[{0, 0, 0, 1}] +  ...

Comment: @AIB replace f@@@ on f/@: Total[f /@ Tuples[Range[0, #] & /@ imax]]

Comment: Thanks..yea figured that out just now :)

Answer (score 3):

Let's assume the following test data

```
k = 3;
vars = Array[i, k];
imax = RandomInteger[{1, 5}, k];
(*
  vars is {i[1], i[2], i[3]}
  imax is here {3, 5, 4}
*)
```

then the nested sum you try to achieve can be written as

```
Sum[f @@ vars, Evaluate[Sequence @@ ({#1, 0, #2} & @@@ Transpose[{vars, imax}])]]
```

Since I used a lot of operators which may not be easy to use by new *Mathematica* users, let me explain the approach in detail. What I want to create first is a *list* of your iterators. For this I first use `Transpose[{vars, imax}]` to create list which has the iteration variable and its upper bound side by side:

```
Transpose[{vars,imax}]
(* Out[5]= {{i[1],1},{i[2],3},{i[3],2}} *)
```

Now I need to transform this into the form `{i[n],0,imaxn}`. Therefore I use an anonymous function `{#1, 0, #2}&`. This function needs to be called like `{#1, 0, #2}&[i[1],1]` to work but we have *sublist* elements. They are in the form `List[i[1],1]`. If I would replace the `List` head with the anonymous function, everything would be fine. This is the reason why `@@@` is used which replaces the heads of the elements *inside* the main list.

```
{#1,0,#2}&@@@Transpose[{vars,imax}]
(* Out[6]= {{i[1],0,1},{i[2],0,3},{i[3],0,2}} *)
```

In the above step we get a *list* of iteration bounds. This is not useful because we need to give them as `Sequence` to `Sum`. Therefore, we again replace a head but this time we replace the `List` head of the main iterator list by `Sequence`. Therefore `@@` is used in contrast to `@@@` which we used to replaced the heads of the *elements of the list*.

This very same trick is used to apply `f` to all iteration variables. We have them in a list `vars` and writing `f@@vars` creates `f[i[1],i[2],...,i[k]]`.

In a last step we have to remember, that `Sum` has the attribute `HoldAll`. Therefore, it does not evaluate our iterator bounds we created so nicely. Instead it sees the whole expression

```
Sequence @@ ({#1, 0, #2} & @@@ Transpose[{vars, imax}])
```

which would lead to an error message because `Sum` expects appropriate bounds. The required evaluation of the above, before `Sum` sees it can be forced by `Evaluate`.

Comment: I didn't take a careful look at your code (I"m at work right now... a little bit short of time...), but I think it is important to put a constraint in the code (I don't know if it already has!) so that i[1] is smaller than imax[1], i[2] smaller than imax[2], etc...

Comment: @RodLm `i[1]` is the iteration *variable*. It has no value. Every nested sum runs from 0 to `imax[n]`.

Comment: Oh, I see... +1 ! Initial iteration value is always zero!

Answer (score 0):

```
k = 3;
Table[{x@i, 0, RandomInteger[{1, 5}]}, {i, k}] /.
  it_ :> {First /@ it, it} /.
 {{var__}, {it__}} :> Sum[f@var, it]
```