# Create simple table with function of column values

Tags: list-manipulation, combinatorics, permutation

I just want to create a simple table:

Three input columns, one output column

Call the inputs `{x,y,z}`, each can take values `{-1,0,1}`

The output column should be some function `f(x,y,z)`

Sample table:

```
x  | y  | z  | f(x,y,z)

-1 | -1 | -1 | f(-1,-1,-1)

1  | -1 | -1 | f(1,-1,-1)
```

etc... (all possible combinations)

Thanks!

Comment: `{##, f[##]} & @@@ Tuples[{-1, 0, 1}, {3}]` but this is very likely a duplicate. Also, Hello :), have you tried anything? What with the documentation for "table"? Is it about *Mathematica*? I'm asking because your syntax does not seem to reflect it is so.

Comment: @kuba Could be a duplicate, but that would be difficult too find. In the meantime, could you use your comment as an answer, so that our answer rate improves? ;-)

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries done :) Also, [related - summation with constraints](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/27042/5478).

Answer (score 5):

Kuba has shown us how to generate the table you want, but didn't give any advice about displaying it in a way looks nice. I'm assuming you are interested in learning a little about formatting as well.

There are, of course, an unlimited number of ways to format data in *Mathematica*. I will discuss just two, one using [`TableForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/TableForm.html) and the other using [`Grid`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Grid.html).

```
data = {##, f[##]} & @@@ Tuples[{-1, 0, 1}, {3}];
```

---

A quick and somewhat dirty method using `TableForm`:

```
TableForm[data, 
  TableHeadings -> {None, {"x", "y", "z", "f(x,y,z)"}},
  TableAlignments -> Right]
```

This produces

[image: table.png]

The one glaring problem with `TableForm` is that the right-aligned last column is ugly. Unfortunately, `TableForm` AFAIK doesn't allow controlling the alignments on a column-by-column basis.

---

#### Edit

*Thanks to Kuba for pointing out that my formatting expression using `Grid` could be much simplified.*

A better method using `Grid`:

`Grid` and its associated functions, such as `Item` and others, allow for much finer control over table formatting. But `Grid` is not always easy to use. Indeed, it can sometimes seem difficult even to accomplish what one hopes will be a trivial bit of formatting. I have seen posts cursing `Grid` as even dirtier than `TableForm`. In this case, `Grid` is easy and gives good results.

```
labeledData = Prepend[data, {"x", "y", "z", "f(x,y,z)"}];
Grid[labeledData,
  Alignment -> {{Right, Right, Right, Left}},
  Dividers -> {{-2 -> True}, {2 -> True}},
  Spacings -> {2, Automatic}]
```

[image: grid.png]

Comment: No need to `Map` with `Item`. `Alignment -> {{Right, Right, Right, Left}}` will do. +1.

Comment: @Kuba. I missed that when reading the docs. Thanks for pointing it out. Will make edit to include this as it is a major improvement.

Answer (score 4):

Straightforward way to achieve this is, just after reading the documentation for **`Table`**:

```
v1 = Table[{i, j, k, f[i, j, k]}, {i, #}, {j, #}, {k, #}] &[{-1, 0, 1}] // Flatten[#, 2] &
```

> ```
> {{-1,-1,-1,f[-1,-1,-1]},{-1,-1,0,f[-1,-1,0]},<<24>>,{1,1,1,f[1,1,1]}}
> ```

A little improved usage of **`Table`**:

```
v2 = Table[Flatten[{i, f @@ i}], {i, Tuples[{-1, 0, 1}, {3}]}];
```

or, what I usually do, not the king of performance but clear and compact **`Apply`**:

```
v3 = {##, f[##]} & @@@ Tuples[{-1, 0, 1}, {3}];
```

variation with **`Array`**:

```
v4 = Array[{##, f[##]} &, {3, 3, 3}, {{-1, 1}}] // Flatten[#, 2] &
```

---

```
v1 == v2 == v3 == v4
```

> ```
> True
> ```

Comment: Wonderful, thanks!! Couldn't figure out the documentation..

Comment: @Kurt Press F1 and use it :) or use online documentation. Take a look at [Table](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Table.html?q=Table&lang=en), especially the 5th syntax. I'm glad you find it useful. Good luck :)